# Is a browser required for Onedrive/Graph Authentication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive, sharepoint-api

It appears via the OneDrive API documentation that a user must always "authenticate" using a web-browser to access the OneDrive API.  This is not helpful for system accounts.  Am I interpreting this correctly?  Or is there a way to achieve step one without a browser:

**Step 1. Get an authorization code**

*To start the sign-in process with the code flow, use a web browser or web-browser control to load this URL request.*

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}
  &response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/graph_oauth.htm#code-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an App-Only integration. See [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) for details on how this process works.

Keep in mind that there are scope differences between app-only and delegated scenarios. Also, app-only scenarios will require Admin Consent before they can operate against a given tenant (see [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/)).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'll look into that asap!

Comment: perfect!  I have that working.  Now I just need to figure out how to to use the access token with one drive.  Does this token only work with the graph API or could I use it with this API?  https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/drive.htm

Comment: I get this error:  10:58:11:000 USER_DEBUG     "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'user'.",   ->>>  Endpoint=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user/{USER GUID FROM AZURE AD}, Method=GET]

Comment: The API is basically the same between OneDrive and Graph but the scopes are not. I would generally recommend sticking with Graph, it is where things are going.

Comment: That sounds like a different error, could you post that as a separate question?

Comment: Here is the new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975760/resource-not-found-for-the-segment-user-application-token

Comment: is it possible to use the app only integration found in the https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service AND get a refresh token?

Comment: There is no refresh token required when using app only (aka OAUTH  client credentials flow). Refresh tokens are only required for delegated (user) scenarios. They're used to keep the user "logged in". Since app only doesn't have a user context, there isn't a token to refresh.

Comment: If I can keep that refresh valid for a year, I could do the browser method, grab the refresh token, and store that in my app.  Would that work to use the authorization bearer refresh token from the server?  If that works I could use that until the Files.readwrite.all is implemented on the app side

Comment: Refresh tokens will last 14 days so you'll need to pull a new refresh token every so often. Keep in mind, you'll need a separate refresh token for each user. Normally you handle this on the server. Users login and make calls to your website, you're website uses that user's bearer token to access Graph and handles refreshing the token as a background job.

Comment: dang!  I read somewhere they could last up to a year.  I can't find the article (you'd know better than whatever that was).  I may be able to use that for testing until that is ready but 14 days would be impractical.

Comment: A given token only lives for 14 days but you can always pull an updated token whenever you like. Every time you refresh you get both an fresh access token **and** refresh token.

Comment: To confirm, that's via the browser not server side code