# Resource not found for the segment user - Application Token

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am able to authenticate and get an application token to use the Microsoft Graph API.  I have set all of the delegated and admin permissions to have access to the users.  I have also used the graph explorer to verify what permissions I need:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

I verified my user GUID (my ID) through Azure AD as well as the Graph Explorer using their https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ call while signed in.  Given I'm using the application token so I must specify a user (see below).

Here is what I'm passing

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user/{my GUID from Azure AD}
Authorization: bearer {myAccessToken}
Content-Type: application/json
```

I suspect it's a syntax issue or a permissions issue.

Comment: It's `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/GUID`, not *user*.

Comment: HA!  Nice catch.  Now I'm getting this-->  "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format";   I am using Content-Type: application/json in the header though.

Comment: You don't need to set Content-Type, because you are not sending JSON. If you want to *accept* JSON, use the Accept header instead.

Comment: If I remove Content-type: application/JSON and have Accpet: application/JSON then I get this:  "Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.",  If I use both accept and content type then I get the same error

Comment: It says I just need the Content-Type and Authorization headers:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_get#request-headers

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You are not writing anything, it is a GET request right?

Comment: totally agree!  System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users// {User GUID}, Method=GET]

Comment: I guess my HttpRequest object stores the header and I was sending both application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded from the previous object.  I ctreated a seperate HttpRequest object with a 'clean' header and it worked.

Comment: you can post your answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL should be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{GUID}
```

And you instead of a Content-Type header, you should send a:

```
Accept: application/json
```