# Microsoft Graph Error - Resource not found for the segment 'root:' when uploading file to OneDrive

Tags: uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

When working on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/5-exercise-upload-files-onedrive) on `Uploading File to OneDrive` from Microsoft Graph OneDrive team, I'm getting the following error at the last line of the code shown below:

**Remarks**: There are some posts online with a related issue, (such as: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44975760/1232087), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42147060/1232087), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61537747/1232087) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61537747/1232087) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35878044/1232087)). But they all seem to have a different context or do not have a response.

**Question**: What could be the issue, and how can we resolve it

> > Resource not found for the segment 'root:'

**Relevant Code**:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = ProviderManager.Instance.GlobalProvider.Graph;

var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
....
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
    // request 1 - upload small file to user's onedrive

  Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
  DriveItem uploadedFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
                                .ItemWithPath(file.Path)
                                .Content
                                .Request()
                                .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ItemWithPath(file.Path)` isn't the path to the file you're uploading, it is the destination path.

For example, if you wanted to upload "SomeFile.txt" to the root of your OneDrive, you would use:

```
graphClient.Me.Drive // The drive
  .Root // The drive's root folder
  .ItemWithPath("SomeFile.txt") // The destination to write the upload to
```

The reason this is currently failing is OneDrive doesn't know what to do with a Windows drive path (i.e. `C:\Files\Documents\SomeFile.txt`). It expects a URL safe drive path (i.e. `/Documents/SomeFile.txt`).

Comment: Oh, so for example my `OneDrive` is mapped to my `Windows - 10`'s file explorer path `C:\MyFolder`. And then `OneDrive` folder structure has built-in folders `Attachments, Documents, Pictures`. Hence, using `graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("/Documents/SomeFile.txt")` would upload the file to `OneDrive`'s built-in folder `Documents`, correct?